# File location is not found in js file

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I develop one js file and also call one js file from it, but I cannot find file. Error is "file not found". I debug in firebug. File url is not generate well. Code is:

```
require(['modules/PageDecorator'], function(PageDecorator){
    //initializing visual ui
    PageDecorator.init();
});
```

it it, **modules** is folder and **PageDecorator** is js file.

url is generated

```
localhost/js/models/PageDecorator.js
```

however I need it to be:

```
localhost/test/js/models/PageDecorator.js
```

**test** is my root folder.

Comment: try `require(['./modules/PageDecorator']` ...

Comment: i try but it not working...